# How to print many-to-many field

Tags: python, django, django-models

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Course(models.Model):
    course = models.TextField(blank=True)
 
class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.TextField()
    last_name = models.TextField()
    course = models.ManyToManyField(Course)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Student, Course

class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'course']

class CourseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ['course']
```

views.py:

```
def students_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        students_form = StudentForm(request.POST)
        if students_form.is_valid():
            students_form.save()

    print(Student.objects.all().values())

    students_form = StudentForm()

    context = {
        'form':students_form
    }
    return render(request, 'courses/courses.html', context)
```

If I print `print(Student.objects.all().values())` than I see student's ID, first_name and last_name. But I don't see in which groups they belong to. How to print that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this for example:

```py
students = Student.objects.prefetch_related("course")

print([(s, list(s.course.all()),) for s in students])
```

Comment: Actually it's course not courses - just in case someone try to make this app. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed, didn't notice that in you code. You are welcome :)